# How to break the build when referenced assembly version changes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, msbuild, sitecore

I have some C# which fixes an issue that is already fixed in a newer release of Sitecore CMS.

I want the fix to be removed if and when we upgrade to the newer version, but that may be some time in the future, and the presence of this fix would be easily forgotten.

Is it possible to break the build or otherwise draw attention to this section of code when the referenced assembly version changes (i.e. higher than v6.5.x) ? A conditional around an `#error` directive may work, but I don't know if or how this can refer to a referenced assembly version?

Note that I'm hoping this can happen at build-time, not runtime, and specifically draw attention to the code in question so that it can be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

Surely to do this all you would need to do would be to make sure your projects have the "SpecificVersion" flag set to true for that reference?

Comment: "Note that I'm hoping this can happen at build-time, not runtime, and specifically draw attention to the code in question so that it can be reviewed."

Comment: As far as I'm aware, setting a specific version requirement will cause the build to fail when the version of the assembly that's referenced has changed, not at runtime.

Comment: More the second part - it doesn't draw any attention to the code in question. It just breaks.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? Might be useful to publish here for others who have taken the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a post-build (or pre-build I suppose) event in Visual Studio? You could run a powershell script or something that will check your assembly version and alert you that the assembly version has changed.

A bit ugly but I think it will work.

Info on build events...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx

Answer (score 0):

While the following solution won't run at build-time, you could do this with unit tests in your health check (assuming you are doing CI with unit tests).

You write a unit test to test that piece of code.  Make sure the unit test asserts the version of the Sitecore DLL reference.  Your health check build will fail when the unit test runs.

You could even gate the check-in with this to make sure nobody could check in without that unit test passing.